# Difference between MVC Action Methods and Web API Action Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Could someone please help me with the below question??

Difference between MVC Action Methods and Web API Action Methods

The only difference I know, was the return types of both methods.

MVC Action method Return Type:
ActionResult  (It is abstract class) and all the derived classes.

Web API action Method return types:
Void
Primitive Type/Complex Type
HttpResponseMessage
IHttpActionResult

Appreciate the further differences between those two. Thank you.

Comment: That is essentially the only difference.  Well, y'know, other than one type is use to create a Web API, the other type is used to create a Web Application.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : thanks for quick comment. However, still checking for 1-2 differences , if any......

Comment: If you're just trying to understand why there are two different categories, your observation already suffices.  If you need to know more than that, my ASP.NET MVC book is a thousand pages long.  So maybe you ought to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Both MVC and Web API action can return `ActionResult` or `IActionResult` type objects. So that is no longer a difference.
Here are few differences if you are still looking for some:

- In Web API, a request is mapped to an actions based on the HTTP verbs. Not for MVC
- Based on the `Accept` header in the request Web API returns data in requested format (e.g. XML or JSON)
- With Web API you can create RESTful services based on Dotnet Framework. But cannot with MVC
- With MVC we can build Web application that can return both data and views but Web API is for sending data only

Answer (score 0):

There are many differences between MVC and Web API, including:

We can use the MVC for developing  the Web application that replies as both data and views but the Web API is used for generating the HTTP services that replies only as data.

In the Web API the request performs tracing with the actions depending on the HTTP services but the MVC request performs tracing with the action name.

The Web API returns the data in various formats, such as JSON, XML and other format based on the accept header of the request. But the MVC returns the data in the JSON format by using JSONResult.

The Web API supports content negotiation, self hosting. All these are not supported by the MVC.

The Web API includes the various features of the MVC, such as routing, model binding but these features are different and are defined in the "System.Web.Http" assembly.
And the MVC features are defined in the " System.Web.Mvc" assembly.

The Web API helps the creation of RESTful services over the .Net Framework but the MVC does not support.